# How do I reset NPCs in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been trying to play the Mage's College quest, but Mirabelle Ervine is frozen in place and can't go anywhere. I can still talk to her, but that's about all I can do. How can I reset her or reset NPCs in general?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd try the `enable` and `disable` console commands.

Make a save game first, and then in the game, open up the [console](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) by pressing <kbd>~</kbd>, then click on  [Mirabelle Ervine](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mirabelle_Ervine). Her [RefID](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs) (0001C1B9) should show up in the screen. If the RefID is correct (meaning you have selected Mirabelle correctly, and not another object), type `disable` and then `enable`.

If it doesn't work, try teleporting her to your location, to try to 'unstuck' her. With Mirabelle still selected in the console (her [RefID](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs) (0001C1B9) still showing up in the screen when you press <kbd>~</kbd> [if not, select her again]), type in `moveto player`.

Comment: Teleporting them has worked for me in the past. Esbern and Jensine got lost and never met up with me, but moveto unstuck them.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the console (` key by default), clicking on the NPC in question, and typing "resetAI". That should reset the NPC's AI and hopefully unstick her. If that doesn't work, you can try "recycleactor", but that may have side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with the stuck Adrianne Avenicci. Following sequence of commands worked:

Console `
Click on the NPC in question - their code will show up.
Commands in sequence (don't have to put the ID if object selected)
1. ResetAI
2. Disable
3. Enable

The character will show up at their default position.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem in riverwood where I told the kid I had made him invisible and ever since then he just stood there not moving...

A few game days later, I returned to riverwood to find everyone just stopped in place outside the inn (near where the kid was) and nobody moved.

The "enable" "disable" command didn't work  on anyone.

What fixed it for me was to attack someone and then type "paycrimegold 0 0" on the console...

I lost the 40 gold for attacking a person, but I didn't get sent to jail nor did my items get taken, if you just use "paycrimegold" you will get taken to prison and items removed.

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the console, click on the actor, and then type `markfordelete`, followed by `disable`. Close the console and move a few steps away, and then open up the console again and type `player.placeatme <base ID of the actor>`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is coming in 5 years late but as I just had this problem and none of the solutions here worked I figured I'd give the solution that worked for me:

1. Summon a hostile mob that will provoke the fight response of your target NPC with  player.placeatme BaseID NumberofObjects

   > (example: player.placeatme 0002D1DE 5 will summon 5 skeletons at your location)
2. Kill or remove the hostile mob(s) once your target NPC reacts to it. The NPC should then move somewhere on their own (this could solve the issue right here)
3. Use console command disable followed by enable on the target NPC. They should now respawn at their correct location with their correct behavior.

Answer (score -2):

The reason why some of the NPCs in Skyrim won't talk to you is you may have the nightingale armor equipped, especially the hood.

Comment: The asker said they can talk just fine, but she won't move.