# How do I completely reset an NPC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recruited Lydia as my follower and had never dismissed her before the bug occured. Here's the current situation:

> (a) Lydia keeps going home.
>
> (b) Lydia's dialog indicates that she is
>   following me (I can tell her to wait, go home, do things for me, or
>   carry my burden).

There's nothing I can do to change these two things. She WON'T wait or go home, but is willing to pick up or exchange stuff when requested.

I also tried `disable`/`enable`, `recycleactor`, `resetAI`, `kill`/`resurrect` and their combination, but the problem remained. When I `set playerfollowercount to 0`, neither Lydia nor my other follower (Serana) went home.

I've never used any follower-related mod. But I do have Vilja with me. The Vilja mod has a feature which enables me to have a friendly fight with any of my followers, and I think the problem occured after my friendly fight with Lydia. What can I do now?

I'm aware of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73205/how-do-i-reset-npcs-in-skyrim), but it does not help me.

Comment: I'm confused. When you dismiss Lydia, does she say she is going home, but doesn't leave, or does she leave and go home to Breezehome?

Comment: @JohnLaviolette My bad. Lydia keeps going home, regardless what I say. And when I talk to her, she always give the normal "follower dialog" as if she were following me.

Comment: Are you saying that you ask her to follow you, but she leaves in the middle of the adventure and returns to Breezehome? Or that she says she is going to go home, but never actually leaves?

Comment: @JohnLaviolette Rephrase - I recruited Lydia as my follower and had never dismissed her before the bug occured. Here's the current situation: (a) Lydia keeps going home. (b) Lydia's dialog indicates that she is following me (I can tell her to wait, go home, do things for me, or carry my burden). There's nothing I can do to change these two things. She WON'T wait or go home, but is willing to pick up or exchange stuff when requested.

Comment: So, she starts to go home, but sticks around? Does she remain in the place where you told her to go home, or does she follow you around?

I ask because I think I had similar behavior, but what I think my answer would be depends on whether she moves or stays put.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other suggestions are working you might have to try spawning an entirely new instance of Lydia. Go wherever you want Lydia to consider home and use a player.placeatme command. (Maybe consider killing or disabling your old instance of Lydia after if this works.)

Note: I'm not entirely sure, but you might have to reset your relationship stats with the new Lydia too.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already tried the appropriate console commands to reset a follower, and you don't have an appropriate saved game to go back to, then there's three other things you could try:

1. Save the game, then immediately load that save. This seems to fix some problems, for example frozen scripts. Fast travel may also work, for essentially the same reason.
2. If the follower continues to follow you after being told to go home, return home yourself and sleep for an extended period of time (24 to 72 hours.) This may reset the follower.
3. If the follower remains where you dismissed her, but doesn't return home, try going through a door that loads another cell, for example leaving a dungeon. Return to check if she has gone home or can at least be sent home correctly. If not, leave the area and sleep for several days, to trigger the "follower has left your service" message.

Answer (score 0):

After exhausting all those other options, I think you'd have to use [ResetQuest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208290/can-you-restart-a-quest-from-the-beginning) on an appropriate quest to reinitiate the follower.

But if you broke your save file with this mod, you're basically out of luck unless you can get a response from its creators.