# Followers sleep on invisible beds

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I completely fixed up the Volkihar ruins and turned about 16 NPCs into vampires, and, using ["My Home is Your Home"](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/62040), I decided to live there.

The problem is that though I commanded them to sleep in coffins at a certain time (in which they do), at other times I find them sleeping next to the dining room table and in other areas of that part of the castle, as though they're in a bed (levitated sleeping).

What can I do to remove this mod so that they can perform normally?

Comment: I do not use this particular mod, but I believe this could be better answered in the mod forums on Nexus.

Comment: What mod manager, if any, do you use? If you are using Mod Organizer 2, you simply need to un-check the mod from the left-hand pane and it will be completely disabled. If manually installed (never recommended) you will essentially need to reinstall. However, regardless of the method, when removing the mod you may need to clean your save with something like ReSaver to remove any dangling scripts left behind in the save file.

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to a complete uninstall - as the scripts of script-heavy mods tend to linger after uninstallation, having detrimental effects - **I'd suggest just disabling the MHIYH AI on the affacted NPCs.**
As per the [mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/62040)'s main page:

> To cancel MHiYH on a Follower use Dialogue *[You don't like your home]* or the MCM.

If you still want to uninstall, be sure to do so only after you made sure that all the followers that have MHIYH behaviour have been 'released' like that.
And, just to be safe, after this step and before uninstalling the mod, make sure you move your character to an interior and wait/sleep for 72 hours, so that certain scripts can reset. For a more thorough resetting, check out the answers [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73205/how-do-i-reset-npcs-in-skyrim).

Comment: The funny thing is that it's only happening in Castle Volkihar ( I find someone sleeping in an invisible coffin in the main entrance hall ) and in the Volkihar ruins ( when you go down into the giant sundial.
I have followers living in various places but this is only happening in Volkihar castle.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting only those affected NPCs, using the option mentioned?

Comment: @ZadekielSephirah Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: This thing only occurs in Castle Volkihar ruins
Nowhere else does this happen and I have NPC followers living everywhere of my choice.

Comment: No I didn't.
I have almost 100 NPCs that I have living somewhere and If I uninstall MHIYH then I would have to go and get each one of them all over again and that would be difficult being that some I got with "Make any one your follower" mod of which I had to uninstall because it had to be updated to a newer version but when I went to update it had to be installed manually and that manual download is a pain in the ass.
It only happens in Volkihar Ruins though.

Comment: The issue is likely due to incompatible mods: one changes Volkihar Castle's layout, and the other supposes all objects are still in their default location, and simply adds 'sleeping' Activators (can't find the name) to these locations. Could you identify mods you're using that do this?

Comment: The only mod I have that relates to sleeping is "Go to bed"
https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/67763